# Choosig split screen rendering?

Tags: rendering

I am using split screens, and the issue I am having is that it uses for rendering randomly one of the split screens, how can I choose which of the screens to be used always for rendering?

Comment: I can't replicate your setup, but if using "image editor" as rendering  display area, try using a duplicate window, maximize it in your preferred scren, and set a single UV/image editor. "image editor" should use the largest area it can find... on my single screen, a duplciated window setup like this works reliably, it seems

Comment: Well its a good idea to render without UI, will it be helpful for you?